# How can I define in JAVA generic type that extends Map object with 2 generic parameters?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

This is my code:

```
public class Configuration <T extends Map<K,V>, K, V> {
    public Map<K, V> fields;

    public Configuration() {
        this.fields = new T<K, V>(); // --> error: Type 'T' does not have type parameters
    }
}
```

Why can't I define a generic object with generic parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of how generics are designed in Java (the generic information is only used at compile time) you can never do `new T()` where `T` is a type parameter.

One possible alternative is to do something like this:

```
public interface ConfigurationMapFactory<K, V> {
    public Map<K, V> createMap();
}

public class Configuration <K, V> {
    public Map<K, V> fields;

    public Configuration(ConfigurationMapFactory<K, V> mapFactory) {
        this.fields = mapFactory.createMap();
    }
}
```

although in that case you could just as easily do this - is there a reason this will not work?

```
public class Configuration <K, V> {
    public Map<K, V> fields;

    public Configuration(Map<K, V> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the sentence *you can never do `new T()` where `T` is a variable* — you cannot know (and so does the compiler!) whether the type did define that constructor or not. Suppose `T` is an `A` type at runtime, maybe only the constructor `A(String str)` is defined, and then `new T()` would be invalid.

Comment: In some other languages (C++) `new T()` would be valid unless you actually tried to create a `Configuration<SomethingWithoutANoArgsConstructor>`

Comment: I did not know that. But I suspect *that's* more prone to errors.

Comment: Ok, your answare is clear, but there aren't costraints like "where T : new()" ?